# How to take the mean of two matrices element wise when NA and NaN are presented?

Tags: r

I want to take the mean of two matrices element wise when NA and NaN are presented. I know similar questions are asked repeatedly, but not with NA and NaN.

For NA + 1.2, the desired mean is 1.2.

```
l1 = 3
l2 = 3
set.seed(1000)
y1 <- matrix(rnorm(l1*l2),l1,l2)
y2 <- matrix(rnorm(l1*l2),l1,l2)

desired_output_if_no_NA <- (y1+y2)/2

y1[1,2] <- NA
y2[2,1] <- NaN

desired_output <- ?
```

Comment: What are your expected output ? it will have NA and NaN in it. Why (y1+y2)/2 not working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified what you want for the mean -1.20 + NaN.  It could be -1.2 or NaN.  It is not hard to get either.

If you want mean(-1.2, NaN) = -1.2, use

```
DO = (y1 + y2)/2
DO[is.na(y1)] = y2[is.na(y1)]
DO[is.na(y2)] = y1[is.na(y2)]
DO
           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -0.9094480  0.1213812 -0.152905201
[2,] -1.2058566 -0.4537133  0.437414704
[3,] -0.2566812 -0.8607652  0.003213122
```

If you want mean(-1.2, NaN) = NaN, use

```
DO = (y1 + y2)/2
DO[!is.nan(y1) & is.na(y1)] = y2[!is.nan(y1) & is.na(y1)]
DO[!is.nan(y2) & is.na(y2)] = y1[!is.nan(y2) & is.na(y2)]
DO
           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -0.9094480  0.1213812 -0.152905201
[2,]        NaN -0.4537133  0.437414704
[3,] -0.2566812 -0.8607652  0.003213122
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array out of matrices:

```
arr <- array(cbind(y1,y2), dim = c(dim(y1), 2))
```

and then use `colMeans` by which you can handle missing values (`NA` or `NAN`):

```
colMeans(aperm(arr, c(3, 1, 2)), na.rm = TRUE)

#           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
#[1,] -0.9094480  0.1213812 -0.152905201
#[2,] -1.2058566 -0.4537133  0.437414704
#[3,] -0.2566812 -0.8607652  0.003213122
```